# KKT conditions of this convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ $f(\cdot,y)$ is convex, and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $f(x,\cdot)$ is convex as well.

Consider the convex optimization problem
$$ \min_x c^\top x \quad \text{subject to: } \ f(x,y^i) \leq 0 \ \ \forall i = 1,...,N,$$
and assume that $x^\star$ is the unique optimizer.

Let $y^1, ..., y^m$ be all the active constraints, i.e. $f(x^\star,y^i) = 0$ iff $i \in \{1,2,...,m\}$.

We know (KKT) that there exist $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_m \geq 0$ such that
$$ c^\top + \sum_{i=1}^m  \lambda_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f( x^\star, y^i ) = 0.$$

Trying to exploit convexity of $f(x,\cdot)$, I am wondering then if there exists $y^\star \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\lambda \geq 0$ such that 
$$ c^\top +  \lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f( x^\star, y^\star ) = 0. $$

Comment: I'm skeptical that it is true. I'm curious what you hope to accomplish with such a result...

Comment: Please clarify the following: $y$ is an m-dimensional vector. So when you write $y^1, ..., y^m$ I understand that you refer to m y-vectors each of dimension m (but the use of m in both cases creates confusion). Do I understand correctly? If yes, what you are saying is that at the x-optimizer, there are m y-vectors that make the f-function's value equal to zero, right?

Comment: That's  true if $f$ is $C^{1}$ and $f : \Bbb{R^n}  \times  \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$